# Yii and Facebook SDK V4.0

Tags: yii, namespaces, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to use the new facebook Graph PHP SDK v4.0 with Yii Framework.

I would like to use Namespaces and the application I am trying to create is a Facebook Page Tab.

I am unable to autoload the facebook SDK

Can someone please help me with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I created a wrapper class for the SDK in extensions/FacebookUtility.php

```
// Include facebook client library
require_once __DIR__ . '/../facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

class FacebookUtility extends CApplicationComponent
{

   public $apiKey;    
   public $secretKey;
           :
           :
   public function connect() { ... }
}
```

Then, in my main.php, under components

```
'facebook'=>array(
  'class'       =>'FacebookUtility',
  'apiKey'     =>'yourapikey',
  'secretKey'  =>'your secret key',
),
```

Then, during my login.

```
$objFacebook  = Yii::app()->getComponent('facebook');

// Establish a connection to facebook
$objFacebook->connect();
```

Comment: @crafer thank you for your comments, the thing is that the new Facebook SDK does not have a facebook.php file, I have not worked with the old one but this newer version uses Namesspaces as they are using PHP 5.3+, Yii is compatible with PHP 5.3 but they use "C" as the differentiation between the Framework and user classes. Due to which the Yii::import and autoloader are unable to load the facebook SDK, this is what I understand I maybe wrong. I am still trying to get answers, I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: he asked for Facebook SDK v4+ which includes lots of classes and has its own namespace. I'm also having this problem and would like to know the solution.