# How to perform Facebook and Google integration using Yii PHP framework and parse.com

Tags: yii, parse-platform

I am developing a web application in which I am using PHP Yii framework and parse.com platform as database. I want perform Facebook integration and Google integration with my application. Usually Yii framework uses mysql as database .I followed all steps mentioned in 
https://github.com/SleepWalker/hoauth/wiki/%5Binstall%5D-hoauth-and-yii-user-extension
it uses

```html
public function findByEmail($email)
  {
    return self::model()->findByAttributes(array('email' => $email));
  }
```

In parse platform we cannot use method findByAttributes();
please suggest me appropriate link or solution to log in to Facebook using Yii framework and parse platform.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/ , https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk

Comment: hello crafter I refereed your link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827508/yii-and-facebook-sdk-v4-0
would you please brief me the definition of connect() function and also let me know how to log in to Facebook ??

Comment: I am using Facebook SDK v4 for my web application which does not contain Facebook.php . what is the way to log in to facebook through Yii application in this scenario?